# How select the rest of the word in incremental search in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

When in incremental search mode in Eclipse, is there a way to select the rest of the word?

For example, suppose I want to find the word “handleReservationGranted”. I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to enter incremental search mode, and start typing the letters “han”. Now suppose I have found the beginning of “handleReservationGranted”. In my search box I have “han”, but I would now like to be able to select the rest of the word, so that the search box contains “handleReservationGranted” instead of “han”.

In Xemacs, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, type “han”, and then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. Now my search term is “handleReservationGranted”, and not “han”. So now if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, I find the next occurrence of “handleReservationGranted”.

I frequently prefer the incremental search over the search dialog, as the search dialog takes too much space on my screen, and most annoying it frequently hides the found matches. 
I am using Eclipse Galileo (3.5.2).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> gives me the list of possible shortcuts in the given context, but none seems to fit what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (no dialog appears).

Then you start typing the word and, when you find it, you'll have te beginning selected.
Now you only have to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to select the rest of the word.

With the word selected, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> it searches for the next ocurrence (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> the previous).

Note: I'm using Eclipse 3.4 but I suppose in 3.5 it works the same way. If it doesn't you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in the editor window (not in the search dialog) and look for 'Incremental Find'.

Comment: Thx, that's kind of what I was looking for. It is not quite as elegant as in emacs, but it gets the job done. Maybe I can just reconfigure the keys, and be happy